How to put a "Loading.." message in Google Sheets while my script is running so that users will know script is still running?
So I have a script being run when a user clicks on a button in sheets. The button is linked to a script. I want a the loading message popped up so they know the script is still running and not edit anything in the tab.
I have tried several scripts I could find online but its not working as intended.
This is what I have tried but its not doing antyhing.
function showDialog() {

var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
// Display a modal dialog box with custom HtmlService content.
var htmlOutput = HtmlService
.setWidth(250)
.setHeight(300);
ui.showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Script Running');

}

So basically what I just want is

Button is clicked, script runs
while script is running, Loading message will appear somewhere in the sheet
Script is finished, Loading message disappears. No additional message pops up.


The script in the question doesn't work because there is a missing method. Calling HtmlService is not enough, you should use a method that returns a HtmlOutput object like HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<p>Loading...</p>');
However, this method does not let the user know when the script is finished. You might open another dialog using SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showDialog(htmlOutput, dialogTitle), as this automatically "closes" the previous dialog.

The following is shown when a script is executed by clicking an image with an assigned script:


Running script
Cancel
Dismiss

Considering the above, there is no need to show an additional message to inform the user that the script is running unless there is something else to tell the user.
Resources

Dialogs and and Sidebars in Google Workspace Documents

Related

Google Sheets OnEdit() - You do not have permission to call a service
Why is my google apps script with an onEdit trigger not invoking a modal dialog (html)?


This is how the screen shows a dialog when running a function assigned to a button (image) in Google Sheets.
Running

Finished

As I mentioned on top of this answer, Apps Script already shows messages when a script is running and when it is finished when the function is executed from a button. The same happens when running the function from a custom menu. However, it might be worth using the dialog to provide additional information to the user, i.e., a reminder not to make changes to the spreadsheet while the script is running, how long it typically takes, etc.
Below is the code used to take the above screenshots. It includes onEditHandler to make it work with an onEdit installable trigger. A simple trigger has several limitations, including a 30-second execution limit and the fact that it's executed with limited authorization.
Code.gs
/**
 * @type {number} Time in seconds that the dialog should wait before closing automatically. 
 */
const TIMEOUT = 10 // seconds;

/**
 * To be assigned to an onEdit installable trigger.
 *
 * @param {EditEvent} e Spreadsheet edit event object
 */
function onEditHandler(e) {
  progressWrapper_(doSomething);
}

/**
 * To be assigned to a button (image)
 */
function onClickHandler() {
  progressWrapper_(doSomething);
}

/**
 * @param {function} function Main function
 * @param {Array} params Function parameters
 */
function progressWrapper_(fn, params) {
  const timeOutMilliseconds = TIMEOUT * 1000;
  let title = '', message = '';
  // Let the user know that the script started
  title = 'Running';
  message = 'Please be wait whil the script run.';
  showDialog_(message, title);

  // do something
   if(Array.isArray(params)) {
    fn(...params);
   } else {
    fn();
   }

  // Let the user know that the script ended
  title = 'Finished';
  message = 'This dialog will closed automatically in a few seconds.'
  showDialog_(message, title, timeOutMilliseconds);
}

/**
 * Show a modal dialog
 * 
 * @param {string} message Dialog message. This might take a bit to load.
 * @param {string} title Dialog title. This show immediately.
 * @param {number} [timeOutMilliseconds] If set, this will make the dialog to be automatically closed after the specified milliseconds.
 */

function showDialog_(message, title, timeOutMilliseconds) {
  const template = Object.assign(
    HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index'),
    {
      message: message,
      title: title,
      timeOutMilliseconds: timeOutMilliseconds ?? null
    }
  )
  const htmlOutput = template.evaluate()
    .setHeight(200);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, title);
}

/**
 * Dummy function. It just pause the script execution for some milliseconds.
 */
function doSomething(){
  Utilities.sleep(20000) // twenty seconds
}

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div><span><?!= message ?></span></div>
    <script> 
      const div = document.querySelector('div');
      const timeOut = <?!= timeOutMilliseconds ?>;
      if(timeOut) div.addEventListener("click", () => {
        setTimeout(google.script.host.close, <?!= timeOutMilliseconds ?>);
        });
      div.click();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>



I understand that but what if the script is in an onEdit trigger? From what I know there's nothing like that when the script is assigned as an onEdit trigger.

Have you tried using a toast?

@Leopard This question is not about onEdit trigger. Follow-up questions should be posted as new questions instead of a comment, but first, take a look at questions like this Google Sheets OnEdit() - You do not have permission to call a service

You left out the method for the HTML service to generate an HTML output.
Here's something you can try.
function showDialog() {

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Display a modal dialog box with custom HtmlService content.
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Loading...')
    .setWidth(250)
    .setHeight(300);
  ui.showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Script Running');

  // Added a sleep so you can see the transition
  Utilities.sleep(3000);

  // This output will close the modal
  var closeModal = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<script>google.script.host.close();</script>')
    .setWidth(250)
    .setHeight(300);
  ui.showModalDialog(closeModal,'Script Running');

}

Based on your feedback in the comment, here is something you can try if you've installed the code to an onEdit trigger to impact only edits on cell A1:
function showDialog(e) {

  // Checks if the cell edited is A1, escapes the function quickly if not
  var cell = e.range.getA1Notation();
  if(cell != 'A1') { return};

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Display a modal dialog box with custom HtmlService content.
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Loading...')
    .setWidth(250)
    .setHeight(300);
  ui.showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Script Running');

  // Added a sleep so you can see the transition
  Utilities.sleep(3000);

  // This output will close the modal
  var closeModal = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<script>google.script.host.close();</script>')
    .setWidth(250)
    .setHeight(300);
  ui.showModalDialog(closeModal,'Script Running');

}

Here's a link to the Event Objects documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

Actually how to do this when only specific cells are edited? Example pop up shows up once a check box is checked or a cell A1 cell value is edited?

I've added feedback if the cell edited is A1 as well as a link to the documentation for Event objects.

@Leopard Follow up questions should be asked as a new question, not in comments.

@Kreeszh It's fine to extend an answer based on comments or even on other answers, but the answer should not include meta commentaries. P.D. "Ideally" an answer should be focused on answering the question. Comments might be deleted and other answers might be deleted or edited.

Is a long shot but may be your answer is this:
At the beginning of your function add a toast (an eternal toast with duration -1) with:
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('Function Runing...', 'Please wait', -1);

And just before funtion end:
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('Function end', 'Done', 1);

This will work into an onEdit() trigger also.
